# What is unsafe about this CSS?

Tags: css

I've been given some CSS by a plugin developer to get the plugin to look the way I want. However, when I go to add it to my wordpress template, the template css editor gives me this message: "Unsafe strings were found in your CSS and have been filtered out."

EDIT: I have confirmed that it's the content: '\f118'; that's being flagged as unsafe. Is it unsafe? Should I avoid using this method on my site for security reasons? Thank you.

```
/*group reaction*/
.activity.single-group .bpsts-reaction-box a.bpsts-mark-reaction, .activity.single-group .bpsts-reaction-box a.bpsts-mark-comment-reaction {
    background: transparent !important;
    border: transparent !important;
    min-height: auto !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
    padding: 2px !important;
    margin:3px !important;
}
/*reaction button*/
.bpsts-open-reaction-div:before {
    content: '\f118';
    font-family: fontawesome;
    font-size: 18px;
    color:#7a7a7a;
}
img.bpsts-icon-img.bpsts-open-reaction {
    visibility: hidden;
}

/*reaction box background*/
.bpsts-reaction-box {
    background: #5d5553; 
}
```

Comment: Unicode F118 is in the private use area, i.e. there's no defined glyph for that code. However as long as you've using a custom font for that element which does define that character it should be OK. IIRC old versions of Font Awesome etc. did that so there probably are ways to do this that would keep your validator happy, but I don't know specifically what. Maybe it's detected that you're not selecting a suitable custom font here. But I'd guess this is "may not render properly" unsafe as opposed to site security unsafe etc.